# paragraph showing as links in html

Tags: html

I am learning HTML/CSS. While practicing I came to this unusual case. I made a `header` and `paragraph` in `section`.

```
<section id="page_section">
    <header>
        <h3>About Me</h3>
    </header>
    <article>
        <p>It's Me</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

And in the browser, both the header and the paragraph are displayed as clickable links in blue and underlined. Why does that happen?

Comment: please make a fiddle so that your problem is clearer.

Comment: [I can't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/9MLpJ/). The problem lies elsewhere. You probably have an unclosed `<a>` element.

Comment: Make a JsFiddle please

Comment: @SecondRikudo thank you. I did not close an anchor tag in <nav>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of the code is fine.

The problem is due to the missing of closing anchor tag in earlier part of your code.